# How can I programmatically create a UIView, with a 'cutoff' UIImageView inside of it?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview, uiimageview

Imagine I want to create a UIView of width and height 100x200.

Then, I want to create a UIImageView of size 100x300 (as that is the size of my image).

However, I want the bottom 100px of the image to be cut off. When I do this right now, the UIImageView appears to be expanding the size of my UIView to 100x300, not its original 100x200.

Here is my code. How can I achieve this?

```
UIView *screeshotView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 100.0, 200.0)];

UIImageView *phoneView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, 100.0, 300.0)];
UIImage *phoneImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"iPhone_6_White.png"];
phoneView.image = phoneImage;

[screeshotView addSubview:phoneView];
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a property called clipsToBounds (defaults to false).  Its in all UIViews.
Just do

```
screeshotView.clipsToBounds = true;
```

This should cut off anything out of the frame of the screenshotView